# 3com 5500G migration to force10 s4810

Tags: switch, qos, dell, force10

I am doing this migration with these 3com switches.So our client told me that the configuration was made for a network administrator who was fired some years ago. So I dont have any kind of documentation so I need to figure what does each command. I am having trouble with 2 ACL and a QOS  policy.

Configuration:

```
#
 acl number 3997
 rule 0 permit ip dscp ef
 rule 1 permit tcp destination-port eq www
 rule 2 permit udp destination-port eq snmp
 rule 3 permit udp destination-port eq snmptrap
 rule 4 permit ip dscp cs6
 rule 5 permit ip dscp cs7
#
acl number 4999
 rule 0 permit type 8868 ffff
 rule 1 permit source 00e0-bb00-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 2 permit source 0003-6b00-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 3 permit source 00e0-7500-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 4 permit source 00d0-1e00-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 5 permit source 0001-e300-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 6 permit source 000f-e200-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 7 permit source 0060-b900-0000 ffff-ff00-0000
 rule 8 deny dest 0000-0000-0000 ffff-ffff-ffff
#
qos-profile default
 packet-filter inbound link-group 4999 rule 8
 traffic-priority inbound ip-group 3997 rule 0 cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound ip-group 3997 rule 4 cos network-management
 traffic-priority inbound ip-group 3997 rule 5 cos network-management
  traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 0 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 1 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 2 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 3 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 4 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 5 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 6 dscp ef cos voice
 traffic-priority inbound link-group 4999 rule 7 dscp ef cos voice
#
```

The ACL 3997 is an ACL for the QOS policy. Is the interesting traffic. I understand that. The second one is a list of MAC addresses allowed in the same QOS policy.

And finally the QOS policy. I have zero experience working with QOS politics in switches. I dont understand how to migrate the QOS policy. I have found some examples but since I dont understand what I am doing I dont want to copy paste a configuration and hope for the best results. Any good resource for a quick crash course for  QOS. at least the basic to understand this policy.

Or if you have the time explain me here what is the meaning of each command.

Thank you

Comment: Just a design question. You are migrating from an old 3com to a 10Gb Data Center switch. Do you value if you need QoS policies? In most modern deployments, I only implement Qos for iSCSI with DCB or similar.